# How to list all git branches created from any commit of a particular branch

Tags: git, merge, contains

There are several questions that are *close* to what I'm asking, but not quite the same.

I want to list all branches, created off of a git branch **at any point in that branch's history**.

Answers to similar questions include using `git branch --contains [branch-name]`, but that doesn't accomplish what I'm after.

Consider the following (simple) example & tree:

```
$ git init
$ git checkout -b master
$ touch master.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial master commit"
$ git checkout -b develop
$ touch develop.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial develop commit"
$ git checkout -b feature/a
$ touch a.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "feature/a commit"
$ git checkout develop
$ git checkout -b feature/b
$ touch b.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "feature/b commit"

master
      \
       \         feature/a
        \       /
         develop
                \
                 feature/b
```

If I want to get all branches that contain the `develop` branch, I can do `git branch --contains develop` and I'll get the following result:

```sh
$ git branch --contains develop

  develop
  feature/a
  feature/b
```

Cool. But let's use a more real-world example (`-`'s are commits) where there are multiple feature branches that are merged in at different times:

```sh
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge feature/a
$ git branch -d feature/a

master
      \
       \         feature/a
        \       /         \
         develop           -
                \
                 feature/b
```

In this case, `feature/a` was completed, merged into develop, and then deleted. And now the latest commit for `develop` is ahead of `feature/b`, which is still being worked on. Now, if I run `git branch --contains develop`, I get the following:

```sh
$ git branch --contains develop

  develop
```

Not cool. What I'd like to see is both `develop` and `feature/b`, as `feature/b` was branched off of an older commit of `develop`.

I have a complicated project with plenty of feature, bugfix, enhancement, etc. branches that have been made off of various points in `develop`'s lifetime, and not all of them have been pulled in, and right now `git branch --contains develop` is pretty useless in telling me what branches are outstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized what *an* answer was as I was wrapping up writing the question (yay for getting thoughts down on "paper").

The command `git branch --contains develop` is only considering the latest commit of the `develop` branch, so you need to get the first commit SHA of the `develop` branch.

Unfortunately, this is where things get tricky. From [Pro Git § 3.1 Git Branching - What a Branch Is](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is):

> A branch in Git is simply a lightweight movable pointer to [a] commit.

Since a branch is just a lightweight pointer, git has no explicit notion of its history or creation date.

I spent way too long hacking together a way to get a branch's original commit SHA and finally came up with one, but there are some prerequisites/limitations.

- You need to know what branch you want the original commit SHA for (in our case, `develop`)
- You need to know the branch it was branched off of and **that branch cannot be ahead of it** (in our case, `master`) - this is definitely not ideal, but anyone is welcome to provide a better answer :)

```sh
$ git branch --contains $(git rev-list master..develop | tail -1)

  develop
  feature/b
```

If you're curious, the stuff in the `$()` is how I get the earliest commit SHA from the git rev list (better approach than original thanks to comment from @alfunx).

Comment: You could replace the command in `$()` with `git rev-list master..develop | tail -1`.

Comment: Thanks @alfunx! That's much less convoluted :) (answer updated)